# Slide.js stop propagation in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm using the slidejs - slidejs.com - library to create a slider on a page embedded into a UIWebView on iOS. I basically want to stop the JS capturing gestures when reaching the end of the panels, and start passing it back to the WebView itself to allow page change.

The JS into the page is prioritized over the gesture recognizer, so probably it needs to be stopped on a specific event to let the WebView gain control over gestures.